# How to define in @ComponentScan path to java classes from another module?

Tags: java, spring, maven

There is spring-application with maven. 
I have root-module and two inner project modules: `webapp` and `utils`.

So, in `utils` I have `@ComponentScan` annotation and paths to source code.

Can I somehow define the path to `webapp` classes in `webapp` for use already wrote classes?
I need just source codes in utils module

Comment: You need to set the inner module as a dependency of the other

Answer (score 1):

You need to define child modules in the pom.xml file parent module:

```
   <modules>
        <module>module-one</module>
        <module>module-two</module>
        <module>module-three</module>
    </modules>
```

Comment: It's good advice, thank you.
my manen compiler fails now with error that there is no webapp module in nexus, so, I think the root cause in this maybe